# How do I unit-test that MatDialog is closed, by mat-dialog-close or otherwise

Tags: unit-testing, angular-material

I have a simple component, which will be displayed as a dialog window by [MatDialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview). In the template of that component, one button is labelled with [mat-dialog-close](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogClose) attribute, which should close the dialog window.

How can I unit-test that the dialog is indeed closed when clicking on the button? Moreover, mat-dialog-close can take an argument and pass it to whomever opened the dialog. How can I verify that the correct value is passed?

It's not about testing the `MatDialog` machinery, more about correctly attaching it to the component. From the test's POV I couldn't care less if the dialog was closed by the button with `mat-dialog-close` or by carefully set timeout that calls `this.dialogRef.close()`. In the latter case I could mock the injected `dialogRef` and spy on calling `close`, but using `mat-dialog-close` is much more convenient, so I'd like to stick to this.

Normally I'd use [TestBed.createComponent](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestBed#createComponent) to create components, maybe this would have to be changed somehow.

Comment: This has been already tested by Angular Material. You need to check that proper attribute was provided in the template.

Comment: @estus: 2 things - how would I do this (apart from regexping the template's text). And I'd like a test that would still pass when I change from `mat-dialog-close` to `this.dialogRef.close()`.

Comment: By doing debug element queries https://angular.io/guide/testing#debugelement . As for dialogRef.close(), you can put Jasmine spy on it. *How can I unit-test that the dialog is indeed closed when clicking on the button* - you don't need to do this in unit tests because these won't be unit tests anymore. You can additionally check that a dialog works as intended in e2e test to be sure.

Comment: @estus True, debugelement would work. I've already mentioned spying on `dialogRef.close`. However neither technique will give me freedom tho swap between `mat-dialog-close` and `dialogRef.close` without changing the test. The outcome, that is 'the dialog is closed with the correct value' is what I'm interested in, and exactly how it was closed is an internal detail that should not be tested (as in 'you don't test private/internal methods'). I'm interested whether the dialog makes correct interaction with the (mocked) outside world, which makes it a unit test. Can someone move this to chat?

Comment: *However neither technique will give me freedom tho swap between ... without changing the test* - good unit tests should never be that loose. If you're making a drastic change to the code like this, it's expected that a test becomes red and needs to be fixed. If you're after testing behaviour, this is what e2e/functional tests are for (emulate click action and check that modal element disappeared), but they aren't a substitution for unit test coverage. An option for a chat appears after several comments, but I personally don't use them on SO because they don't play well with offline messages.

Comment: @estus I completely disagree. From the component's interface POV (complete interface, not API), such a change is not a change, so I would expect the test to pass, as with every other refactoring. And from a test design perspective: A test requirement of 'clicking that button closes the dialog with a value of _x_' seems like a sane one for me. A test requirement of 'clicking that button calls dialogRef.close(x)' is not that bad, but when I try to formulate the other one, I get  'this button has "[mat-close-dialog]="x"? Sorry, where's the user action in that one?

Comment: Again, you will never see a good unit test being that loose, because it is a hell to debug when it fails. *Sorry, where's the user action in that one?* Should there always be user action? Are you trying to stick to BDD? This is a matter of methodology.  By testing behaviour alone and not implementation you will end up with 'unit tests' that overlap with integration/e2e tests (both test behaviour and involve many moving parts), yet still don't provide 100% code coverage.

Comment: I never do such things because this approach doesn't provide efficient coverage, so I'm unable to help here. Consider checking Angular guide on testing to get some ideas how the components are usually tested (as a rule of thumb, only current unit is real, each and every other is mocked).  I'd suggest to update the question with relevant details, because it doesn't really explain the approach you're after and doesn't contain your tests that could give some ideas. It's more about functional testing and BDD.

Comment: In your particular case the thing that really suggests that this test belongs to e2e (Protractor) and not unit (Karma) is that there's no promise to chain when you emulate user action and wait for result. This sort of tests is naturally handled by e2e frameworks (e.g. Protractor's browser.wait) and tend to be slow - unit tests are supposed to be fast to run often (most TestBed tests can be synchronous), but this one will require random setTimeout delay to assert that modal element has disappeared. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit late to the party, but here's how I did this.  As mentioned in the comments above, a spy on the injected MatDialogRef is needed.  The part that OP may have missed is that behind the scenes that will be called by material with the `mat-dialog-close` attribute AS WELL AS when `this.dialogRef.close()` is called manually from within the component.

My component only uses the following template:

```
<button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
```

and the following test passes just fine:

```
it('should close the component if cancel is clicked', () => {
    mockDialogRef.close.calls.reset();
    page.cancelButton.click();
    expect(mockDialogRef.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

(I use a page class to define what is on the page for clarity when reading `.spec` files, as suggested in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#use-a-page-object).)

This exact same test passes if instead I call a function and execute `this.dialogRef.close()`.

While I am not testing a value passed, the OP did ask about that.  Something like this should do the trick:

In the template:

```
<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Cancel</button>
```

And now in the test:

```
it('should close the component and pass back correct data if cancel is clicked', () => {
    mockDialogRef.close.calls.reset();
    page.cancelButton.click();
    expect(mockDialogRef.close).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
});
```

I hope this helps.