# How do I write simple test to check the behaviour of MatDialog in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-form',
  templateUrl: './my-form.component.html',
})
export class MyFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('company') company: CompanyInfo;
  private config: ConfigInterface | null;

  constructor(private companyService: CompanyService, private something: Something, private dialog: MatDialog) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    ....
  }

  theMtehodWhichIWantToTest(company: string) {
    if (someTest.indexOf(domain)) {
      this.dialog.open(MyAllertComponent, {
        data: {
          title: 'blah',
        },
      });
    }
  }
}
```

My poor and failing unit test:

```
describe( 'MyFormComp', () => {
  it('should open MatDialog if email is from popular domain', () => {
    const dialog = {} as MatDialog;
    const comp = new MyComponent({} as CompanyService, {} as Something, dialog);
    comp.getCompanys(company);
    expect(dialog.open(AlertComponent));
  });
})
```

The error message: `TypeError: dialog.open is not a function`

Yes, I know why I have this error message - I am not mocking the dialog correctly and the functon `open` is not available. Can someone tell me how to make `open` available using [jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/pages/docs_home.html) (I.e. how to properly mock MatDialog?)

I am quite new to js unit testing so, just telling me what to google will not be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the beforeEach method to create spy's for your component dependencies:

```
emailServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('EmailService', {});
somethingSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Something', {});
dialogSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('MatDialog', ['open']);
```

Then provide these for your Testmoudle:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [YourComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: EmailService, useValue: emailServiceSpy },
    { provide: Something, useValue: somethingSpy },
    { provide: MatDialog, useValue: dialogSpy },
  ],
  imports: [],
}).compileComponents();
```

And in your Test you can check if your spy-function get called:

```
expect(dialogSpy.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: thanks. I did so bu now I have: `createSpyObj requires a non-empty array or object of method names to create spies for thrown
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
`

Comment: my misktake, i updated my example; here the example for jasmine - createSpy
https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

Comment: Still the same: `createSpyObj requires a non-empty array or object of method names to create spies for thrown
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined` I also added the following line: `spyOn(dialogSpy, 'open');` but it did not help

Comment: mh... maybe this:     openSpy = jasmine.createSpy('open');
    dialogSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('dialog', { open: openSpy });