# Cannot read property 'afterClosed' of undefined when unit testing MatDialog in Jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog, jasmine, angular-material

I get the following error from Karma Jasmine:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'afterClosed' of undefined`

I searched sincerely, but I could not find a solution in Stack Overflow or in other sources.

This is how I open the `MatDialog` in my component:
(Like [documented](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview))

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

public openDialog(): void {
    const dialogReference: MatDialogRef<any, any> = this.dialog.open(myDialogComponent, {
        width: '1728px'
    });

    dialogReference.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
    });
}
```

This is my unit test config:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
            myRequestComponent
        ],
        imports: [
            MatDialogModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule
        ],
        providers: [
            { provide: MatDialog, useValue: {} },
        ],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(myRequestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Here is my unit test:

```
it('openDialog() should open a dialog', () => {
    spyOn(component.dialog, 'open');

    component.openDialog();

    expect(component.dialog.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Do I have to mock the MatDialog or the MatDialogReference?

Comment: Have you added `myDialogComponent` to your declarations array in your `TestBed` config? Can you show that config as well?

Comment: My guess is that you are mocking the `MatDialog` implementation, and your mock has no configured return for the `open` call

Comment: @AmitChigadani Thanks, I just did. On test run, it throws: "TypeError: ctor is not a constructor". I have added my config to the description.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I tried this mock, but it doesn't change an thing:

    const mockedMatDialog: { open: () => any } = {
        open: () => ({ afterClosed: '' })
    };

Comment: I´ll add an answer

Comment: @jasie Took a bit longer as I had too look at some internals from jasmine

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Lets break your issue step by step.

**First**, by registering

```
providers: [{ provide: MatDialog, useValue: {} }],
```

Your test bed will inject a an object with no behavior (eg. instance methods/members) whenever `MatDialog` needs to be resolved.

This isn't truly necessary, as you are importing the `MatDialogModule` into your test bed, so an instance of `MatDialog` can be resolved without issues. <del>But lets stick to your approach.</del> This solution will require you to remove that line.

**Second**, by doing:

```
spyOn(component.dialog, 'open')
```

you are installing a *proxy* for the `open` instance method in the object referenced by `component.dialog`. In this case, the empty object that you registered previously.

<del>Despite the fact that the object does not have such a member, jasmine will dynamically add the proxy in its place. That is why you don´t see an error like `this.dialog.open is not a function`.</del>

**Lastly**, whenever interacted with, the proxy will record information about those interactions and redirect the calls to the original `open` member. Because there was no original implementation, [a function with no return will be used in its place](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/110c092c9ece00cd6c882bd573b911c35ff73478/src/core/SpyStrategy.js#L16), which will finally trigger the `accessing foo of undefined`.

**TL;DR;**

Remove `{ provide: MatDialog, useValue: {} }` and use the following in order to mock the required `MatDialogRef` instance:

```
import { EMPTY} from 'rxjs';

it('openDialog() should open a dialog', () => {
    const openDialogSpy = spyOn(component.dialog, 'open')
        .and
        .returnValue({afterClosed: () => EMPTY});

    component.openDialog();

    expect(openDialogSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort of explaining it to me, I appreciate it.
It is worth to emphasise that the providing of MatDialog MUST NOT happen (to make your solution work - otherwise "Error: <spyOn> : open() method does not exist" will be thrown).

Comment: Another hint: "Empty is deprecated: Deprecated in favor of using {@link index/EMPTY} constant." Didn't know until now.

Comment: This is not working anymore with the latest release

Comment: For some reason karma now checks the type of the returnValue and you should use :     
`const dialogSpy = spyOn(matDialog, 'open').and.returnValue({afterClosed: () => EMPTY} as any);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below

```
{provide: MatDialog, useClass: MatDialogMock} // Add this in the providers array


export class MdDialogMock {
  // When the component calls this.dialog.open(...) we'll return an object
  // with an afterClosed method that allows to subscribe to the dialog result observable.
  open() {
    return {
      afterClosed: () => Observable.of({})
    };
  }
};
```

OR

```
     let dialogSpy: jasmine.Spy;
     let dialogRefSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj({ afterClosed : of({}), close: 
     null });
dialogRefSpyObj.componentInstance = { body: '' };

beforeEach(() => {
    dialogSpy = spyOn(TestBed.get(MatDialog), 'open').and.returnValue(dialogRefSpyObj);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I just added your first solution: It throws the exact same error. Also, it causes: "Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'."

Comment: Your second solution is incomplete: dialogSpy variable is not initialised and not used. But anyway, this throws: "Error: <spyOn> : open() method does not exist"

Comment: For those who are downvoting, he did not put the code earlier. So, I dont know his imports and how he was using. The answer I gave works perfectly fine.