# Mocking Angular Material Dialog afterClosed() for unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-material, karma-jasmine

I am opening my mat-dialog with the following function:

```js
accept() {
  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AcceptDialogComponent, {
    data: {
      hasAccepted: false
    }
  })
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
    if (result.hasAccepted === true) {
      this.leadService.acceptLead(this.holdingAccountId, this.lead.id)
        .pipe(
          takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)
        )
        .subscribe(acceptLeadRes => {
            console.log(acceptLeadRes);
            this.leadService.updateLeadAction('accept');
          },
          (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(err);
            this.router.navigate(['/error']);
          });
    }
  });
}
```

I am attempting to write a test for this function that simply fires the afterClosed() so that I can check if my service method that makes a backend call is called.

component.spec.ts (beforeEach Testbed creation)

```js
beforeEach(async (() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LeadCardComponent, AcceptDialogComponent],
      imports: [
        requiredTestModules,
        JwtModule.forRoot({
          config: {
            tokenGetter: () => {
              return '';
            }
          }
        })
      ],
      providers: [
        ApplicationInsightsService,
        JwtHelperService,
        // { provide: LeadsService, useValue: leadServiceSpy }
      ],
    }),

    TestBed.overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
      set: {
        entryComponents: [AcceptDialogComponent]
      }
    });
  TestBed.compileComponents();
}));
```

component.spec.ts (test)

```js
it('Return from AcceptLeadDialog with hasAccepted equals true should call acceptLead endpoint', () => {
  let matDiaglogref = dialog.open(AcceptDialogComponent, {
    data: {
      hasAccepted: false
    }
  });
  spyOn(matDiaglogref, 'afterClosed').and.callThrough().and.returnValue({
    hasAccepted: true
  });
  spyOn(leadService, 'acceptLead').and.callThrough();
  component.acceptLead();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  matDiaglogref.close();
  fixture.detectChanges();

  expect(leadService.acceptLead).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The test currently fails with a "Expected spy acceptLead to have been called." I am failing on understanding how to test the function and execute some sort of mock MatDialogRef so that I can check if the conditions of my test pass.

Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated

**Update Working Test implemented from Accepted Answer**

```js
it('Return from AcceptLeadDialog with hasAccepted equals true should call acceptLead endpoint', () => {
  spyOn(component.dialog, 'open')
    .and
    .returnValue({
      afterClosed: () => of({
        hasAccepted: true
      })
    });
  spyOn(leadService, 'acceptLead').and.callThrough();
  component.acceptLead();
  expect(component.dialog).toBeDefined();
  expect(leadService.acceptLead).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to mock the `MatDialog` `open` method? Doing that should allow you to return a mock `MatDialogRef` that you are in control of and you can manually trigger the `afterClosed` observable to emit a new value.

Comment: Could I trigger afterClosed manually and still test the logic of it's response being a condition for additional code to execute?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? That it is the complete solution because I am also looking to test the opening and closing of a popup

Comment: @dna It has been a while but the accepted answer worked for my tests

Comment: Is it possible to have the complete test that works

Comment: Updated with working test. hope that helps

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can test Angular Material Dialog's afterClosed method this way:

1. `import { of } from 'rxjs';`
2. spy on the dialog and return an observable for the `afterClosed()` method

```
spyOn(component.dialog, 'open')
     .and
     .returnValue({afterClosed: () => of(true)});
```

Basically, the `afterClosed()` of the dialogRef is expecting an Observable. So we spy on the component's dialog open method and return an Observable for the `afterClosed()` method by using the `of` operator from `rxjs`.

You can then replace the `of(true)` from the `returnValue` with your own data what you are sending in the `afterClosed()` of the dialog in the main component.

Comment: it is throwing error.  can you help me with that.  Argument of type '{ afterClosed: () => Observable<boolean>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MatDialogRef<unknown, unknown>'.
  Type '{ afterClosed: () => Observable<boolean>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'MatDialogRef<unknown, unknown>': _overlayRef, _containerInstance, id, componentInstance, and 18 more.t

Comment: @SunilSoni, I am facing the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: @SunilSoni Well `.open` is normally supposed to return a `MatDialogRef`. In this case you are only returning a fraction of that object, so TypesScript is complaining about it. To satisfy TypeScript you can cast the value using: `.and.returnValue({ afterClosed: () => of(data) } as MatDialogRef<unknown>)`. But be aware that TypeScript complains were quite valid. If calls to any other method of `MatDialogRef` are made within the test, it's going to fail trying to call `undefined`.

Comment: @RodNolan see my other comment on this question please.

Comment: Thanks @Elias for your help

Answer (score 41):

I solved this problem as the first post by @Adithya Sreyaj but added the next change:

```js
spyOn(component.dialog, 'open')
    .and
    .returnValue({
        afterClosed: () => of(true)
    } as MatDialogRef<typeof component>);
```

Comment: This should be the no.1 top answer.

Comment: Although this only works if `dialog` is a public member of `component`, no?

Comment: The best answer. Instead of providing all functions and properties of MatDialogRef, only change what you need.

Comment: I am not sure this will work after Jest 28. We must now use jest.spyOn and can no longer us `.and.returnValue...`

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing the whole point of unit testing the component. From my understanding:

1. You have a function `accept()` which creates subscription to the closing event of `this.dialog`
2. You should write unit test to verify the logic that the subscription is getting created and the service is called.
3. Make `dialogRef` global to `component` rather than keeping it private to `accept()`. This would help you test your code better. `private` variables can't be access during unit testing.

So:

**component.ts**

```
accept() {
 this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AcceptDialogComponent, {
  data: {
    hasAccepted: false
      }
    })
 this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
  if (result.hasAccepted === true) {
    this.leadService.acceptLead(this.holdingAccountId, this.lead.id)
    .pipe(
      takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)
    )
    .subscribe (acceptLeadRes => {
      console.log(acceptLeadRes);
      this.leadService.updateLeadAction('accept');
    },
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      console.log(err);
      this.router.navigate(['/error']);
    });
   }
 });
}
```

**spec.ts**

```
it('should create subscription to Modal closing event and call "acceptLead()" of "leadService" ', () => {
    spyOn(component.dialogRef, 'afterClosed').and.returnValue(
        of({
            hasAccepted: false
        })
    );
    spyOn(component.leadService, 'acceptLead').and.callThrough();
    component.accept();
    expect(component.dialogRef).toBeDefined();
    expect(component.dialogRef.afterClosed).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.leadService.acceptLead).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I am not able to get your solution working. I could make dialogRef  global to the component but I am opening several different dialogs from this component, would this not conflict with being able to do that?

Comment: @BrianStanley : If you are opening several `dialogRef`, the you'll have to make separate `refs` for all of them globally. If you keep the variable as private, you wont be able to test it using `jasmine`